# Removing background for YouTube video

Tags: youtube

I would like to remove the background completely in a video I want to record for YouTube, because I don't want others to see my messy house or where I am because it would just look too bad. What tools do I need to accomplish this task, in terms of hardware and OSk requirements on Windows and software, and is it easy do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a greenscreen. This can be done with household items, but will be a lot easier with equipment of about 150$.

You hang a green cloth behind you, light it up good and evenly.

Then in an editing/streaimng software you simply use the Grenn Screen/Key/Chroma Key tool.

There are cameras which can do it too, but those are expansive and don't work as well.